# Get Only Few Elements of a Group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a grouped by Pandas dataframe:

```
id    date    temperature
1  2011-9-12   12
   2011-9-12   20
   2011-9-18   12
   2011-9-19   90
2  2011-9-12   15
3  2011-9-12   15
   2011-9-16   15
```

Here, each id has different numbers of records of temperature.

I want to fix them, to say the average number of records per id (say 3). If some records are missing I want to put zeros initially.

I want to **keep the more recent records.**

i.e. My final dataframe should be:

```
id    temperature
1     20
      12
      90
2     0
      0
      15
3     0
      15
      15
```

Here is the numpy code which gives error on line:

```
s=df.groupby(level=0)['temperature'].apply(list)
s1=s.tolist()
arr = np.zeros((len(s1),3),int)
lens = [3-len(l) for l in s1]
mask = np.arange(3) >=np.array(lens)[:,None]
arr[mask] = np.concatenate(s1) ## Error
    pd.DataFrame({'id':s.index.repeat(3),'temperature':arr.ravel()})
```

I suspect the error is due to the fact that my data can have more than 3 rows for an id.

How to fix the issue?

Comment: you want random *n* records or unique records?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar 
I want to keep the more recent n (say, 3) records, if not aviable put 0, as in the example above. thanks, i have edited the question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with `ascending=False` for counter and [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) by `MultiIndex` created by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
print (df)
   id       date  temperature
0   1  2011-9-12           12
1   1  2011-9-12           20
2   1  2011-9-18           12
3   1  2011-9-19           90
4   2  2011-9-12           15
5   3  2011-9-12           15
6   3  2011-9-16           15
```

---

```
N = 3
df['new'] = df.groupby('id').cumcount(ascending=False)
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['id'].unique(), range(N-1, -1, -1)], names=['id','new'])
df1 = (df.set_index(['id', 'new'])['temperature']
        .reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .reset_index())

print (df1)
   id  temperature
0   1           20
1   1           12
2   1           90
3   2            0
4   2            0
5   2           15
6   3            0
7   3           15
8   3           15
```

EDIT:

If MultiIndex `DataFrame`:

```
print (df)
              temperature
id date                  
1  2011-9-12           12
   2011-9-12           20
   2011-9-18           12
   2011-9-19           90
2  2011-9-12           15
3  2011-9-12           15
   2011-9-16           15

print (df.index)
MultiIndex(levels=[[1, 2, 3], ['2011-9-12', '2011-9-16', '2011-9-18', '2011-9-19']],
           codes=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2], [0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1]],
           names=['id', 'date'])
```

---

```
N = 3
df['new'] = df.groupby('id').cumcount(ascending=False)
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.levels[0], range(N-1, -1, -1)], names=['id','new'])
df1 = (df.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .set_index('new', append=True)['temperature']
         .reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .reset_index())

print (df1)
   id  temperature
0   1           20
1   1           12
2   1           90
3   2            0
4   2            0
5   2           15
6   3            0
7   3           15
8   3           15
```

Comment: thanks, but again i get the same error keyerror: set_index(''new, append=True)['id'] -> keyerror id

Comment: @tstseby - It means no column `ACCTNBR`, what is `print (df.info)`  ?

Comment: @tstseby - Also is possible some whitespace in column names, check it by `print (df.columns.tolist())`

Comment: yes, the id column is not appearing in df.columns.tolist() (only new and 'temperature' appear), however, it apperars in df.index (which has two names: 'id' and 'date')

Comment: @tstseby - Hmm, so `.set_index('new', append=True)['temperature']` - not working?

Comment: thank you so much! it works, i had a wrong column name in the above line. One more question, how to get the output in the form of the original data itself, i.e. id and then its 3 temperatures, like in the initial input?

Comment: @tstseby - Try remove last ` .reset_index()` - but because no MultiIndex, then are values repeated. If rmove last `.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .reset_index()` get also counter level and first `id` are not repeated.

Answer (score 2):

A little lengthy solution but works:

```
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by='date'))
                .drop('id', axis=1)['temperature'].groupby(level=0).tail(3)
                .groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: np.pad(x, (3-len(x),0), 'constant'))
                .reset_index()

   id   temperature
0   1  [20, 12, 90]
1   2    [0, 0, 15]
2   3   [0, 15, 15]
```